# macOS Sierra (10.12) tells me my iPhone passcode is wrong

Tags: iphone, password, macos

I just upgraded my MacBook Pro to macOS 10.12 Sierra, and as i try to link my iPhone it tells me "wrong passcode". I can open and use my phone with that same passcode but my Macbook Pro mid 2012, will only allow limited access.

Please help.

Comment: To clarify, you are getting this error in iTunes?

Comment: What does 'link my iPhone' mean?